# Unable to fetch city name

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I'm using Google Maps in my Android application where the user can enter locations. Sometimes I have the issue, "Unable to fetch city name". I tried to check my Wi-Fi connection and the GPS, both are  working but still this issue hits my application randomly.

Comment: post your code here please.

Comment: Actually don't have code..
I am testing the application..